# Dash - how to escape strange path characters

Tags: shell-script, shell, dash

If the follow strange directory is created:

```
a"␤

b"
```

In bash or zsh one can do:
cd a$'\n'b        or
cd 'a'$'\n''b'

What is the equivalent for dash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only equivalent is essentially what you wrote:

```
cd a"
"b
```

(or some other arrangement of quotes). String literals can contain whitespace, including line breaks, and preserve it literally as part of the word it's in. You can't use a backslash for the line break because that invokes [newline joining](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_01) and just deletes the line break entirely, so either single or double quotes are your options.

In this case you could also use [command substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) with e.g. [`printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) to process that same `\n` escape sequence:

```
cd "a$(printf '\nb')"
```

The final `b` is required *within the `printf`* because trailing newlines are deleted by command substitution, so this won't work if the filename literally ends with newline character. You can also use it for other escapes, such as `\a` for a BEL byte.

There is no direct POSIX or dash equivalent for `$'...'` ANSI-C quoting ([yet](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=249)).

Comment: Thank you Michael, your solution provided a useable workaround.